# Windows remote terminal stuck at black screen

Tags: windows, terminal, windows-server-2016

from time to time, on of our about 30 terminals turn black as seen on the screen and there is no way, other than force sign out.
[image]

Sending ctrl-alt-end with virtual keyboard does nothing, nor alt-pageUp. Nothing works even trying that physically at the terminal.

Do anybody know what to do with it? Or any ideas? Cant find any solution. Thanks
Windows Server 2016
Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.4225)